# how to use a variable representing conditions in np.where for column in pandas with list values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to use np.where for calculations inside column based on other conditions.
And i wish to modify the else condition.
Also i have to use **
df1['matches'].fillna('[0]',inplace = True)** else it was giving differnt error

Code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('one.txt',sep = '\t')
df1['matches'].fillna('[0]',inplace = True) 
df1['scorehigh?']  = df1['league'].apply(lambda a: 'yes' if a == 'Active' or a == 'Super Active' else 'no')
df1['greaterthan10?'] = (['yes' if any(int(a)>10 for a in i) else 'no' 
                                      for i in df1['matches'].str.findall('\d+')])

m=np.where((df1['scorehigh?']=='yes')) & (df1['matches'] != '[0]')                    

df1['Finals?']  = np.where((df1['scorehigh?']=='yes') & (df1['greaterthan10?'] == 'yes'), 'YES', m)
a=df1['Finals?'].value_counts()
print(a)
```

Error:

```
setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Input:

```
league          matches
Active          [[1, 0, 50,], [2, 0, 14,]]
Active          [[1, 0, 0,], [2, 0, 4,]]
Active          [[1, 0, 50,], [2, 0, 14,]]
Super Active    [[1, 0, 50,], [2, 0, 14,]]
Low             [[1, 0, 50,], [2, 0, 14,]]
Low             [[1, 0, 5,], [2, 0, 5,]]
Low             [[1, 0, 40,], [2, 0, 10,]]
Super Active    
Super Active    
Super Active    
Super   
Low
```

Expected Output:

```
league               matches                                   greater_than_10?
Active               [[1, 0, 50,], [2, 0, 14,]]                yes
Active               [[1, 0, 0,], [2, 0, 4,]]                  no
Active               [[1, 0, 50,], [2, 0, 14,]]                yes
Super Active         [[1, 0, 50,], [2, 0, 14,]]                yes
Low                  [[1, 0, 50,], [2, 0, 14,]]                no
Low                 [[1, 0, 5,], [2, 0, 5,]]                   no
Low                 [[1, 0, 40,], [2, 0, 10,]]                 no
Super Active           [0]                                     no
Super Active           [0]                                     no
Super Active           [0]                                     no
Super                  [0]                                     no
Low                    [0]                                     no
```

Expected After using **value.counts**:

```
Yes: 3
No: 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with:

```
m=np.where((df1['scorehigh?']=='yes')) & (df1['matches'] != '[0]')
```

If no paramater after mask output is array of positions of matched values.

---

```
df1['matches'].fillna('[0]',inplace = True) 


df1['scorehigh?']  = df1['league'].apply(lambda a: 'yes' if a == 'Active' or a == 'Super Active' else 'no')
df1['greaterthan10?'] = (['yes' if any(int(a)>10 for a in i) else 'no' 
                                      for i in df1['matches'].str.findall('\d+')])
```

Use nested [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with specify `None` if no match, also for second mask was use only `df1['matches'] != '[0]'`:

```
df1['Finals?'] = np.where((df1['scorehigh?']=='yes')&(df1['greaterthan10?'] == 'yes'), 'YES',
                 np.where(df1['matches'] != '[0]', 'NO', None))
```

Or [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) :

```
df1['Finals?'] = np.select([(df1['scorehigh?']=='yes')&  (df1['greaterthan10?'] == 'yes'), 
                            df1['matches'] != '[0]'], ['YES', 'NO'], default=None)
```

---

```
print (df1)
          league                     matches scorehigh? greaterthan10? Finals?
0         Active  [[1, 0, 50,], [2, 0, 14,]]        yes            yes     YES
1         Active    [[1, 0, 0,], [2, 0, 4,]]        yes             no      NO
2         Active  [[1, 0, 50,], [2, 0, 14,]]        yes            yes     YES
3   Super Active  [[1, 0, 50,], [2, 0, 14,]]        yes            yes     YES
4            Low  [[1, 0, 50,], [2, 0, 14,]]         no            yes      NO
5            Low    [[1, 0, 5,], [2, 0, 5,]]         no             no      NO
6            Low  [[1, 0, 40,], [2, 0, 10,]]         no            yes      NO
7   Super Active                         [0]        yes             no    None
8   Super Active                         [0]        yes             no    None
9   Super Active                         [0]        yes             no    None
10         Super                         [0]         no             no    None
11           Low                         [0]         no             no    None

a=df1['Finals?'].value_counts()
print(a)
NO     4
YES    3
Name: Finals?, dtype: int64
```

If used both condition output is different:

```
df1['Finals?'] = np.select([(df1['scorehigh?']=='yes')&  (df1['greaterthan10?'] == 'yes'), 
                            (df1['scorehigh?']=='yes') & (df1['matches'] != '[0]')], 
                            ['YES', 'NO'], default=None)
print (df1)
          league                     matches scorehigh? greaterthan10? Finals?
0         Active  [[1, 0, 50,], [2, 0, 14,]]        yes            yes     YES
1         Active    [[1, 0, 0,], [2, 0, 4,]]        yes             no      NO
2         Active  [[1, 0, 50,], [2, 0, 14,]]        yes            yes     YES
3   Super Active  [[1, 0, 50,], [2, 0, 14,]]        yes            yes     YES
4            Low  [[1, 0, 50,], [2, 0, 14,]]         no            yes    None
5            Low    [[1, 0, 5,], [2, 0, 5,]]         no             no    None
6            Low  [[1, 0, 40,], [2, 0, 10,]]         no            yes    None
7   Super Active                         [0]        yes             no    None
8   Super Active                         [0]        yes             no    None
9   Super Active                         [0]        yes             no    None
10         Super                         [0]         no             no    None
11           Low                         [0]         no             no    None

a=df1['Finals?'].value_counts()
print(a)
YES    3
NO     1
Name: Finals?, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @Anonymus - So expected output is `greater_than_10?` or `Finals?`

Comment: expected output is 'Finals?', with counts YES = 3 and NO = 4